# Same route on first link it works, but on second not. Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.6, laravel-controller

Route file web.php:

```
Route::get('/download/received/{image_id}/{isoriginal?}', 'DownloadController@download_recv_image');
```

View:

```
    <li><a href="{{action('DownloadController@download_recv_image', [$image->id, true])}}">Download {{strtoupper($image->extension)}}</a></li>

    <li><a href="{{action('DownloadController@download_recv_image', $image->id)}}">Download PNG</a></li>
```

Function in controller:

```
    public function download_recv_image($image_id, $original=false){...}
```

This is function for download received image. When I click on first link in view route is called and function is executed. But on second link where I'am not sending second parameter then it returns me error 404 and it looks like it cant catch route.

(I have another function for download user images, with same logic for route definition in another two links and there everything works.)

Comment: look and see what URL ends up in the anchor tag for that second one

Comment: when I click on second one, route is http://localhost:8000/download/received/2, but it returns error 404

Comment: I have tried to return some string at the start of controller function just to test it if it's get inside but it isnt.

Comment: It didnt worked but I have found the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have found where the problem is.

That's because above that route I have another route called:

```
Route::get('download/{image_id}/{isoriginal?}', 'DownloadController@download_user_image');
```

I have changed second route to /received/download instead of /download/received

It's messing up because both routes have the same beginning and parameters ar messed up.